# how to select the most recent records

Tags: hive, conditional-statements, max

[image]

Select id, name , max(modify_time)
from customer 
group by id, name

but I get all records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order by modify_time desc and use row_number to number the row for id,name combination.Then select each combination with row_number = 1

```
select id,modify_time,name
from (
        select id,modify_time,name,row_number() over(partition by id order by modify_time desc) as r_no
        from customer
     ) a
where a.r_no=1
```

Comment: this doesn't need a grouping

Comment: `partition by id` is needed.

Comment: Thank you VK_217 ! . It works. I will accept it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Ids are unique, which means grouping them by the id, will result in the same table.

My suggestion would be, to order the table by "modify_time" descending and limit the result to 1 (Maybe something like the following):

```
Select id, name modify_time from customer ORDER BY modify_time DESC limit 1
```

Comment: Oh your ids are not unique after all. Sorry about that. Then you would need a group by after all, but the rest would stay the same

Comment: The limit 1 only select one records. I want to select all most recent records in the table

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the whole table as a result is because you are grouping by id AND name. That means every unique combination of id and name is returned. And since all names per id are different, the whole table is returned.

If you want the last modification per id (or name) you should only group by id (or name respectively).